# YouTube Client Side Uploads From iOS Device

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to build an iOS app that uses the Google-API-Objective-C-Client (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) to upload YouTube videos from a device. In the example code provided, it is assumed that a user of the library will uploading a video to their own account, and takes them through a sign-in process that interrupts the app flow and either presents a modal window or webview to ask for the user's permission to post on their account.

The issue is that in the app I am building, the video will be posted to our account (not the user's). I can't figure out how to complete the oAuth process and obatin a key without presenting a modal to the user in the process.

The class I'm trying to get around is GTMOAuth2WindowController.

Any help from someone who has used this API before would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For privacy issues, users have to upload videos into their accounts first. There is one way to get around it. You can use [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/). So user's would still upload their videos with their own credentials, but then you have to option to moderate and approve those videos to have them in your playlist.